# Is it possible to delegate a single function call, to a WebWorker?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, web-worker

I have some existing code(running in the browser), that follows a certain interface, which I do not want to break/refactor.

There's a sequence of function calls. One of those functions, which isn't under my control(comes from some library), performs heavy calculations, that freeze the main thread, rendering the UI useless for about 40 seconds.

My idea is to use a WebWorker of course. Problem is, that from the examples i see- a WebWorker requires its own isolated script, that communicates with the main thread via "messages". Refactoring my code to fit this "scheme", would be tedious. I'll give a simplified example to what I want to achieve:

```
class MySimplifiedFacade{
    consturctor(){
        ...
    }

    someLightMethod(params){
        //Do something light
    }

    //THIS IS THE FUNCTION I WOULD LIKE TO SOMEHOW ISOLATE INTO A WEBWORKER
    veryHeavyCalculations(params){
        someExternalLibrary.heavySynchronousCalculation(params)
    }
}
```

The only thing in the sequence of actions, that actually requires a WebWorker, is this one function called "veryHeavyCalculations" in the example.

Is it possible to somehow isolate a specific "piece of code" inside a WebWorker?
Problem is, according to my understanding, is  that any thing I pass to a WebWorker via messages, must be "serializable", whereas in my case I would need to pass a reference to some existing object.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, `params` must be serialisable. Other than that, the refactoring is simple: you write a worker script that imports that library, receives messages, calls `someExternalLibrary.heavySynchronousCalculation(params)`, and posts back the results.

Comment: What is the specific library and what does it do for 40s? Why do you "*need to pass a reference to some existing object*"?

Comment: Regarding your idea: This is more or less what I'm doing right now. The thing is, that this worker needs to call all other methods of that library, because it exposes a very statefull object, and I cannot just use the worker for one method call(this method call assumes that other methods were already called before).
Regarding your question: Being that I wanted to only delegate one function call, i would need to pass a reference to that function, while preserving its context. It's some internal library from my company.

Comment: Yeah, that's not possible. Try to remove as much statefulness as you can. The good thing is the library is from your own company, which means you can rewrite it :-) Either by completely removing its hidden preconditions and allowing the function to be called by itself, or by adding functions to de/serialise the internal library state.